# How to hide a button on a template in a certain URL path for Meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am quite new to Meteorjs, but finding it great to use.

I want to know what is the best way to hide an element of a template depending on the route/url. Since I would like to use the same template again elsewhere but without certain elements in it.

Thanks

my code according to below solutions

My helpers

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  ownPost: function() {
    return this.userId === Meteor.userId();
  },
    commentsCount: function() {
    return Comments.find({postId: this._id}).count();
  },
  routeNameEqual: function(name){
    var routeName= Router.current().route.getName();
    return routeName === name;
  }
});
```

My html

```
{{#if routeNameEqual 'postsList2' }}
 <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="discuss btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
 {{else}}

 {{/if}}
```

Crucial!! it is the route name not the route's path

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using [iron:router package](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router), you can use.

```
if(Router.current().location.get().path == 'some check'){
     $('#button').hide();//use jQuery
  }else{
    $('#show').hide();//use jQuery
 }
```

Also check the [iron:location package](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-location)

Also you tag javascript, so here is another solution using javascript

```
 if(document.URL == 'some check'){  // or use window.location.href 
         $('#button').hide();//use jQuery
      }else{
        $('#show').hide();//use jQuery
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If parsing paths seems tedious you can also use Route *names* (again, assuming iron:router)

```
Router.current().route.getName()
```

If you want to avoid manipulating the DOM or you want to avoid including the content in the template in the first place then use a template helper

HTML:

```
<template name="foo">
{{#if routeNameEqual 'bar'}}
  .. content
{{/else}}
  .. alternate content
{{/if}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  routeNameEqual: function(name){
    return Router.current().route.getName() === name;
  }
});
```

Note that here the helper is expecting a 'name' parameter which is the route name. In the HTML we're looking to see if the route name is 'bar'. This gives you flexibility to use it for any route.

Comment: does this return the template name or the route name

Comment: The *route* name. In my development I usually have template name == route name